# Query JSON object using a loop in R

Tags: json, r

I am fairly new to R. I have the below sample JSON. I am trying to query a portion of the json once a criterion has been satisfied. In this case, if the search condition of sergeant is met, then I should be able to populate a variable grade with the appropriate value.

```
{
  "result": {
    "members": [
      {
        "rank": "sergeant",
        "grade": "A"
      },
      {
        "rank": "trooper",
        "grade": "B"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My Java code would be on these lines roughly:

```
JSONObject res = jsonData.getJSONObject("result");

JSONArray mem = res.getJSONArray("members");

for (int i=0; i< mem.length() ;i++) {
   JSONObject memdata=mem.getJSONObject(i);

if (memdata.rank=="sergeant") { 
    grade=memdata.rank;
}
```

How do I query similarly in R? How do I get the grade for the sergeant? From whatever I have tried, I keep getting a list and am not able to stop at "sergeant" so I can extract his grade.  I am using the `jsonlite` package.

Comment: Please try to post valid JSON and better formatted code snippets in the future. You might also want to read the [vignette that comes with the package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-mapping.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tidyjson](https://github.com/sailthru/tidyjson) offers quite a few helpful ways to work with `JSON`.  Here is an answer with your data.  The vignettes in the package are very, very helpful, so I encourage you to read through them if possible.

```
library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)

'{
"result": {
  "members": [
    {
      "rank": "sergeant",
      "grade": "A"
    },
    {
      "rank": "trooper",
      "grade": "B"
    }
    ]
}
}
' %>%
  as.tbl_json() %>%
  enter_object( "result", "members" ) %>%
  gather_array( ) %>%
  spread_values(
    "rank" = jstring("rank")
    ,"grade" = jstring("grade")
  ) %>%
  filter( rank == "sergeant" )
```